# Почему изменения которые я вношу в winscp не отображаются на сервере

Tags: telegram-bot, django-admin, winscp

Делаю задание: нужно допилить функционал **telegram bot** написан с использованием **django**. Так вот, я делаю изменения в **winscp** и по идее они должны выгружаться на сервер, но этого не происходит. В чем причина, может я не правильно понимаю, как работает **winsc?**

Comment: Не известно, как оно у Вас там устроено, но обычно код вначале коммитится в репозиторий, а потом билд скриптами/ci-cd заливается на сервер

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Если вы просто подменили питон код (т.е. изменили *.py файлы), то этого мало. Нужно перезапустить само приложение (бот)

Comment: Именно, так я и сделала. Спасибо, за ответ.